# Creating a 3D function in Matlab using meshgrid

Tags: matlab

This should be a really simple question, but for some reason I'm getting unreasonably confused and the Matlab documentation isn't helping.

Given a uniform grid of coordinates `(x_i,y_j,z_k)`, I want to make a 3-dimensional array `F` in Matlab such that `F(i,j,k)=f(x_i,y_j,z_k)`.  The following is obviously incorrect:

```
x=linspace(-1,1,100)  % uniform mesh on [-1,1]^3
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x);

f=X.*Y.*sin(pi*Y.*Z)   % for example
```

Do I need to use `permute` somewhere? I know that I could simply make a triple loop, but as we know that is slow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid` to avoid the unwanted permutation between first and second dimensions.

From the documentation (see also [here](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html)):

> MESHGRID is like NDGRID except that the order of the first two input
>       and output arguments are switched (i.e., [X,Y,Z] = MESHGRID(x,y,z)
>       produces the same result as [Y,X,Z] = NDGRID(y,x,z))

Comment: Yes, avoid meshgrid when possible! +1 I recently [went on a rant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22461766/2778484) about this same thing. So much confusion seems to arise from `meshgrid`.

Comment: @chappjc Your rant is well justified I think :-) My favourite one is [`'`versus `.'`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258444/transfer-function-in-time-domain)